# How to write unit test case for this scenario

Tags: python-2.7, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

I'm trying to write a unittest case for the below method in my main.py

```
def create_tmp_dir(tmp_dir): 
    logger.info('{app} Creating directory: {arg}'.format(
       app=app_log, arg=tmp_dir))
    mkdir_cmd = 'mkdir -p ' + tmp_dir
    try:
       utility.simple_cmd(mkdir_cmd)
    except Exception, exc:
       logger.critical('{app} Unable to create dir: {arg}'.format(app=app_log, arg=exc))
       exit(1)
```

the simple_cmd method in utility.py does:

```
def simple_cmd(cmd):
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

this is my test_main.py

```
def test_create_tmp_dir_raises_exception_on_blank_dir():
    with patch('utility.simple_cmd'):
        with pytest.raises(Exception):
            main.create_tmp_dir('')
```

when I run pytest, it says exception is not raised

```
        with patch('utility.simple_cmd'):
            with pytest.raises(Exception):
>               main.create_tmp_dir('')
E               Failed: DID NOT RAISE <type 'exceptions.Exception'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@phd thanks for your response, actually I cant change the source code. so solution that I found is, that I should be setting the side_effect to Exception and raising a SystemExit.

```
def test_create_tmp_dir_exits_on_exception():
    with patch('utility.simple_cmd') as SimpleCmdMock:
        SimpleCmdMock.side_effect = Exception
        with pytest.raises(SystemExit):
            assert main.create_tmp_dir('Some_Directory') is None
```

Answer (score 1):

`create_tmp_dir` doesn't raise `Exception` — it catches it and converts to `SystemExit` which is a subclass of `BaseException`, not `Exception`, hence your `pytest.raises(Exception)` doesn't catch it.

Reraise the exception instead of exiting:

```
except Exception, exc:
   logger.critical('{app} Unable to create dir: {arg}'.format(app=app_log, arg=exc))
   raise
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.